# How to check browser ver/name from Lotus Notes Java agent?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Assume it's not possible.
When I run agent from my browser by:
http://www.xxxxxxx.com/mydb.nsf/MyAgent?OpenAgent

I want in this java MyAgent get the browser's name/ver (i.e. HTTP_User_Agent)

Is there any workaround?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to work with document context.
You get a document that has all the CGI- variables as items in it. Here is example code from the [designer help](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_DOCUMENTCONTEXT_PROPERTY_JAVA.html):

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

        try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

      // (Your code goes here) 
          Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
          System.out.println
        (doc.getItemValueString("http_user_agent"));

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Link. That works.. I just used wrong CGI variable